# OpenLDAP: slaptest not parsing variable in config

Tags: ldap, openldap

When running the command:

```
slaptest -f slapd.conf
```

Against my slapd config file I'm getting this error message

```
51dfbb3e lt_dlopenext failed: (back_@BACKEND@) file not found
slaptest: bad configuration file!
```

It seems to me the `slaptest` is missing something when running the test. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a 100% answer, but still: I am quite sure that slapd itself never parses *any* kind of variables in its config – especially not the database backend; it would make most sense to put it directly in the config, since it's not something you can change every day.

The variables are probably intended to be replaced by some other tool that takes such configuration templates – maybe Debian's *debconf* (I don't know if it uses a similar syntax), maybe a custom shellscript full of `sed s/@BACKEND@/hdb/g`... Without knowing where you got the config file from, it's hard to tell.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. The config file with the `@BACKEND@` variable comes from the default installation (`apt-get install slapd`)

Answer (score 0):

For my part, I was using the new configuration style with a `slapd.d` folder instead of the deprecated `slapd.conf` config file. So instead of running :

```
slapcat -f /usr/share/slapd/slapd.conf -l backup.ldif
```

which gave me the error you refer to, I ran :

```
slapcat -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d -l backup.ldif
```

which produced a valid `backup.ldif` file. (my location of the `slapd.d` folder and of the `slapd.conf` file might not be standard, use `find` on your system to locate yours).